# ctypes wrapper for function returning by value objects of a C++ class with destructor

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, destructor, return-by-value

Can `ctypes` wrap functions that return objects (not pointers/references) of a C++ class with a destructor? The example below segfaults when calling `lib.init_point_by_value`:

**foo.cpp**:

```c++
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    ~Point();
};

Point::~Point() {
     cout << "Point destructor called" << endl;
}

Point init_point_by_value(int x, int y) {
    cout << "init_point_by_value called" << endl;
    Point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    return p;
}

Point& init_point_by_ref(int x, int y) {
    cout << "init_point_by_ref called" << endl;
    Point* p = new Point;
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    return *p;
}

void cleanup_point(Point* point) {
    cout << "cleanup_point called" << endl;
    if (point) {
        delete point;
    }
}

}
```

**foo.py**:

```
import ctypes


class Point(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ctypes.c_int),
        ('y', ctypes.c_int),
    ]


def setup_lib(lib_path):
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
    lib.cleanup_point.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(Point)]

    lib.init_point_by_value.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
    lib.init_point_by_value.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Point)

    lib.init_point_by_ref.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
    lib.init_point_by_ref.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Point)

    return lib


lib = setup_lib('./foolib.so')

p1 = lib.init_point_by_ref(3, 4)
lib.cleanup_point(p1)

# seg faults
p2 = lib.init_point_by_value(5, 6)
lib.cleanup_point(p2)
```

Compile and run it with:

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o && g++ foo.o -shared -o foolib.so && python foo.py
```

Output:

```
init_point_by_ref called
cleanup_point called
Point destructor called
init_point_by_value called
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: of course it segfaults, it's trying to delete some non-allocated memory.

Comment: Nope it segfaults in `init_point_by_value`, it doesn't even reach `cleanup_point`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with warnings enabled and I get:

```
x.cpp(17): warning C4190: 'init_point_by_value' has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT 'Point'
    which is incompatible with C
```

This is due to the object having a destructor.  Remove the destructor and it should accept it.

Another issue is the return type of `init_point_by_value` is incorrect.  It isn't a `POINTER(Point)` but just a `Point`:

```
lib.init_point_by_value.restype = Point
```

Finally, don't try to free the returned-by-value object.

Result with the fixes as follows (adapted slightly for my Windows system):

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#define API __declspec(dllexport) // Windows-specific export
extern "C" {

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

API Point init_point_by_value(int x, int y) {
    cout << "init_point_by_value called" << endl;
    Point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    return p;
}

API Point& init_point_by_ref(int x, int y) {
    cout << "init_point_by_ref called" << endl;
    Point* p = new Point;
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    return *p;
}

API void cleanup_point(Point* point) {
    cout << "cleanup_point called" << endl;
    if (point) {
        delete point;
    }
}

}
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes

class Point(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ctypes.c_int),
        ('y', ctypes.c_int),
    ]

def setup_lib(lib_path):
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
    lib.cleanup_point.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(Point)]

    lib.init_point_by_value.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
    lib.init_point_by_value.restype = Point

    lib.init_point_by_ref.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
    lib.init_point_by_ref.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Point)

    return lib

lib = setup_lib('test')

p1 = lib.init_point_by_ref(3, 4)
print(p1.contents.x,p1.contents.y)
lib.cleanup_point(p1)

p2 = lib.init_point_by_value(5, 6)
print(p2.x,p2.y)
```

**Output**

```
init_point_by_ref called
3 4
cleanup_point called
init_point_by_value called
5 6
```

Comment: Thanks, the destructor is indeed the real issue. The problem is I'm trying to wrap a 3rd party class that (a) [has a destructor](https://github.com/guestwalk/libffm/blob/master/ffm.h#L27) and (b) [is initialized by value](https://github.com/guestwalk/libffm/blob/master/ffm.cpp#L264). For some reason `init_model` works (unlike the `init_point_by_value` in the example) but the destructor is not called implicitly, and adding a cleanup function akin to `cleanup_point` causes double freeing errors.

Comment: Btw gcc (v7.3.0) doesn't issue a warning even with `-Wall`